# Automatically generate all template instantiations

Tags: c++, templates, template-instantiation

Given a template like

```
template<bool f> void f();
```

for which only a finite number of (known) instantiations exist: is it possible to automatically generate all those? Sure it's no issue to write

```
template void f<false>();
template void f<true>();
```

but this might get lengthy if there are enums or multiple template parameters involved.

Edit: The question is academic, I suppose, as my actual problem is not too large to instantiate manually. Still, I'm curious.

Edit 2: For those who wonder why I want this: I am working on a project in which I experiment a lot, so I often rewrite code. I therefore try to move all template implementations to source files, to avoid long compilation times, which leaves me with stating in that source file all instantiations I need.

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're trying to solve, or is this an academic question?

Comment: Write a code generator if you have to. You do know this is only needed to improve build times right?

Comment: @PepijnKramer What do you mean with your second sentence?

Comment: You don't need to create explicit instantiation to make your code work.

Comment: The second sentence means that creating explicit instantiations will only parse the templates once. In other cases it may be parsed for each compilation unit.